# How can I read messages from an iothub azure device from python?

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying take the messages from an iot device ,but i get the following error : Exception caught in background thread. Unable tot handle.

```
['azure.iot.device.common.transport_exceptions.ConnectionDroppedError: Unexpected disconnection\n']
```

tried the following code:

```
import time
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient

RECEIVED_MESSAGES = 0

connection_string = "="

def message_handler(message):
    global RECEIVED_MESSAGES
    RECEIVED_MESSAGES += 1
    print("")
    print("Message received:")

    # print data from both system and application (custom) properties
    for property in vars(message).items():
        print ("    {}".format(property))

    print("Total calls received: {}".format(RECEIVED_MESSAGES))

def main():
    print ("Starting the Python IoT Hub C2D Messaging device sample...")

    # Instantiate the client
    client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(connection_string) 

    print ("Waiting for C2D messages, press Ctrl-C to exit")
    try:
        # Attach the handler to the client
        client.on_message_received = message_handler

        while True:
            time.sleep(1000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("IoT Hub C2D Messaging device sample stopped")
    finally:
        # Graceful exit
        print("Shutting down IoT Hub Client")
        client.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The Error indicates that your IoT device is experiencing an unexpected disconnection from Azure IoT Hub.

Comment: `time.sleep(1000)` statement in your loop. This will cause your program to sleep for 1000 seconds (almost 17 minutes) between iterations, which might not be what you intended. You can reduce this sleep duration or remove it altogether if you want the code to listen to messages continuously.

Comment: The original code had a sleep duration of 1000 seconds (almost 17 minutes) between iterations in the while loop. The modified code reduces it to 1 second, making it more responsive to incoming messages.

Comment: Using this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/c2d-messaging-python#receive-messages-in-the-simulated-device-app), I am able to read the message from the IoT Hub. Please check your Connection String, Ensure the Device is Registered, Check for Network Issues and reduce the sleep duration.

Comment: For more details refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041271/devices-reconnect-to-azure-iot-hub-every-65-minutes). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Error indicates that the Azure IoT device is experiencing an unexpected disconnection from the Azure IoT Hub.

- Using this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/c2d-messaging-python#receive-messages-in-the-simulated-device-app), I am able to read the message from the IoT Hub.
- Create an Azure IoT [hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-through-portal#create-an-iot-hub) and  register a new [device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-through-portal#register-a-new-device-in-the-iot-hub) in the IoT hub.
- Replace with IoT device connection [string](https://i.imgur.com/3DIJTwD.png).

**Code:**

```py
import time
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient

# Replace with your IoT device connection string
connection_string = "HostName=sam.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=mytestdevice1;SharedAccessKey="

RECEIVED_MESSAGES = 0  # Initialize the received message count

def message_handler(message):
    global RECEIVED_MESSAGES
    RECEIVED_MESSAGES += 1
    print("Message received:")
    print(" Data: {}".format(message.data))
    print("Total calls received: {}".format(RECEIVED_MESSAGES))

def main():
    print("Starting the Python IoT Hub C2D Messaging device sample...")
    client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(connection_string)
    print("Waiting for C2D messages, press Ctrl-C to exit")
    try:
        client.on_message_received = message_handler
        client.connect()
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)  # Reduce the sleep duration
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("IoT Hub C2D Messaging device sample stopped")
    finally:
        print("Shutting down IoT Hub Client")
        client.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- Send the message from the Azure IoT Hub like below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Is this code different from OP's question? Does it address the issue?

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer Op did use complete this method ```RECEIVED_MESSAGES += 1
print("Message received:")
print(" Data: {}".format(message.data))
print("Total calls received: {}".format(RECEIVED_MESSAGES)) ```

Comment: yes, I addressed the issue and  code is almost the same

Comment: Ok, maybe you can highlight the part where it solves OPs issue, I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer Op's main ask is `How to read messages from an IoT hub Azure device from Python` and he facing disconnection from the Azure IoT Hub. I reduced `time.sleep(1000)` from `time.sleep(1)` to make the code more responsive to incoming messages.

Comment: Thanks Sampath, probably good to put that in the answer.

Comment: @SPT I'll leave that to the poster of the question. Also, this answer doesn't solve the issue, as time.sleep() doesn't block or break connection. Sampath even links to the docs, that has the user's exact code in there.